# Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `Userform` with `Textboxes` in it.

When I try to click the `Submit` button in the form, I get an error `Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"`. Why am I getting that error?

Here's the code

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
    Sheet2.Activate
    Dim lastRow2 As Long
    lastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lr4).Value = CDate(Me.tbDate).Value
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & lr4).Value = Me.tbProduct.Value
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & lr4).Value = Me.tbQty.Value
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & lr4).Value = Me.tbPrice.Value        
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.tbDate.Value = Date
    Me.tbProduct.Value = ""
    Me.tbQty.Value = ""
    Me.tbPrice.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to specify which line it fails on.  What is `ssheet` here?  Should that be `Sheet2` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams updated the code, yes its sheet2

Comment: OK but which line is the problem?

Comment: If you keep fixing your code it will no longer be a useful question...

Comment: I have changed `lastRow2` back to `lr4` else my answer looses it's meaning. I have also indented the code and made some minor changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because `lr4` is `0`.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lr4).Value = CDate(Me.tbDate).Value
```

More Clarification

Once you fix the value of `lr4`, you will not get the `Applicaiton Defined Error` as mentioned in your question. You will however get a syntax error becuase of `.Value` in `Cdate`. Remove that or change it to `CDate(Me.tbDate.Value)`

Comment: ah yes thats it ! i forgot to change the lr4

Comment: I thought it was the `.Value` part ...  CDate doesn't return an object

Comment: @TimWilliams: That will give a `Syntax Error`. `lrr=0` will give `Application defined..` error :)